# How to determine the best sealing time for private Clique

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, clique, geth-clique

I have several transactions to be stored in my permissioned blockchain with PoA Clique.

With the transactions information in mind, how do we determine the best sealing time for private Clique' blocks? As we know the default is 15 seconds which is sometimes considered not fast enough or even too fast depending on the transacions

(I'm using Geth client v1.9.6-stable-bd059680)

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer to this will depend on the concrete usecase.

Basically there are two main parameters you can tweak on:

- block time (how fast to produce blocks?)
- block gas limit (how much to include in a block?)

How you're going to set these parameters, will depend on your environment:

- UX (e.g. User waiting for x seconds to get a confirmation for a transaction)
- node performance
- number of signers
- network lag
- storage consumption
- ...

What I can tell is that there are also danger areas with geth Clique, which can lead to deadlocks in the consensus algorithm like described here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/18402 To us it happend for instance with blockTime=5s, gasLimit=16M, signers=4